# Having trouble linking my timer buttons (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

UPDATE: Thank you to everyone that offered a solution. And it appears XCode was just being a bit buggy because I came back to my project and it's working fine now. Again thank you!

first thank you to anyone who offers some help.

I am attempting to link my buttons and nothing happens when I try to drag them to their connection.

As you can see the selection does not highlight to allow for the connection. I was able to connect the Date Picker but have had no luck with the start, stop, or pause button. I am learning from the Instructable tutorial.

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be awesome

Comment: Try Command + Option + Shift + Z and then restart Xcode. Sometimes, the mapping done with Xcode gets kind of buggy. That command will reload and clean things (it fixes any floating pointers). Restarting is just for safe practice for cleaning it. You could also try cleaning your build.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly....the Cmd+Opt+Shift+Z didn't work but I will give cleaning my build a try

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Edit your question to include the code that defines the `pauseButton` outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot link to an item in your storyboard from an outlet and the item on the storyboard does not highlight, the usual issue is that you have not set the correct class/object type. For instance, if you have specified a sub-class of `UIButton` type in your `IBOutlet` declaration but have a plain `UIButton` on the storyboard, or a totally different class than `UIButton` in your your IBOutlet declaration, you might not be able to link the items.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that sometimes even if you have the correct class, this BUG can occur. (IF you have everything else set straight as from the comments and other answers here)

Instead of cleaning projects and restarting Xcode as others suggest (which maybe is needed sometimes)

**Another solution:**

1: Create a property `IBOutlet` manually typed where you want to connect it.

2: Once created, drag the property `IBOutlet` **from the code** to the element in the storyBoard instead of the other way around.

You will notice things will connect without problems and everything will start working again.

[image]